# VF override on a standard button on SF1

Tags: salesforce1-app

We are using Visualforce to override the standard edit button on the account object. When we click on the edit button the page hangs on Salesforce1. Is there a workaround to handle redirects in Page reference /Action tags to get this achieved?

Comment: This still happening?

Comment: This Working as designed.

Comment: S1 cannot handle redirects to standard pages.

Answer (score 1):

Create the exact replica of the page and the controller and enable this page for SF1. Create an action with this page on account and place it to the required page layout.
Remove the SF1 access from the page you were previously using.

Hope this will help.